# array_slice не срабатывает внутри foreach

Tags: php, массивы

Проблемный участок кода:

```
public function create($file)
{
    $file = file($file);

    $country = preg_grep('/\((\w+)\)(\s?(\w+)\s?(\w+))/', $file);

    foreach ($country as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->collection[$value] = array_slice($file, $key, next($country));
    }
}
```

Входной файл:

```
(UK) Great Britan
Zelma Belyavskaya
Danielle Hughes
(PH) Philippines
Marione Bayunggan
Maria Hadap
```

Нужный результат:

```
array [
    (UK) Great Britan => [Zelma Belyavskaya, Danielle Hughes],
    (PH) Philippines => [Marione Bayunggan, Maria Hadap]
]
```

Текущий результат:

```
array [
    (UK) Great Britan => [],
    (PH) Philippines => []
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы там намудрили. next вернет первый раз 3, а второй раз ему нечего возвращать - массив кончился. Я бы так делал

```
$file = [
'(UK) Great Britan',
'Zelma Belyavskaya',
'Danielle Hughes',
'(PH) Philippines',
'Marione Bayunggan',
'Maria Hadap'
];

    $collection = [];
    $key = '';


    foreach ($file as $value)
    {
        if (preg_match('/\((\w+)\)(\s?(\w+)\s?(\w+))/', $value)) { 
            $key = $value;
            continue;
            }
        $collection[$key][] = $value;
    }
print_r($collection);
```

получим

```
Array
(
    [(UK) Great Britan] => Array
        (
            [0] => Zelma Belyavskaya
            [1] => Danielle Hughes
        )

    [(PH) Philippines] => Array
        (
            [0] => Marione Bayunggan
            [1] => Maria Hadap
        )

)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Рад был помочь!